# MySQL | Selecting data from another table

Tags: mysql, select

I am trying to use a foreign key in order to setup a system where I can refer to this table to get a friendly name, rather than using the id in the api.

Currently, I have it set up like this...

```
| id | friendly_name
| 1  | starters  
| 2  | desserts
```

And I have another table like this...

```
| id | type | price | desc
| 1  | 1    | 3.99  | This is the desc
```

I want to use the type to refer to in the api so i have `/api/menu/{id}/{type}` but I want it to be written like `/api/menu/1/starters`.

I am currently trying this code but it is returning every item in the database

```
SELECT
   m.item,
   m.description,
   m.price
FROM
   menu m,
   types t   
WHERE
    m.restaurant_id = :restaurant_id
AND 
    t.id = :type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `ON` clause to your join and you need to select by `type.friendly_name`not `type.id`.

```
SELECT
   m.item,
   m.description,
   m.price
FROM
   menu m INNER JOIN types t ON m.type = t.id  
WHERE
   m.restaurant_id = :restaurant_id
   AND 
   t.friendly_name= :type
```

Comment: This doesn't work, it just returns all of the data in the database

Comment: @tallent123 you should mark it as helpful if it worked for you ;-)